# rc-year-calender not updating the event

Tags: reactjs, calendar

i need help in rc-year-calender.
I am using rc-year-calender and i am facing problem in updating any event on a dialog box.
this is my code

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const me = this;
    const form = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (this.validateForm()) {
        const holiday = {
            occasion: this.state.fields.occasion,
            for_date: this.state.fields.for_date,
            is_restricted: this.state.fields.checkbox,
        };
        let config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token,
            }
        }
        if (this.state.fields.id === null) {
            axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + `holidays`, { holiday }, config)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.status == 200) {
                        me.setState({
                            openNotification: true,
                            openNotificationType: 'success',
                            openNotificationMessage: 'Holiday added successfully'
                        })

                    }
                }).catch((er) => {
                    me.setState({
                        openNotification: true,
                        openNotificationType: 'error',
                        openNotificationMessage: this.parseError(er)
                    })
                })
        }
        else {
            axios.put(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + `holidays/` + this.state.fields.id, { holiday }, config)
                .then(res => {
                    me.setState({
                        openNotification: true,
                        openNotificationType: 'success',
                        openNotificationMessage: 'Holiday updated successfully'
                    },
                    )

                }).catch((er) => {
                    me.setState({
                        openNotification: true,
                        openNotificationType: 'error',
                        openNotificationMessage: this.parseError(er)
                    })
                })
        }
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ validated: true });
    }
}
```

handleSubmit function is working as the post and put api handler
if it gets holiday id null then it will create new and id found then update the holiday

here is my render function

```
render() {
    const holidays = []
    this.state.holidaysList.forEach((holiday) => {
        let start = moment(holiday.for_date).toDate()
        holidays.push({ id: holiday.id, name: holiday.occasion, startDate: start, endDate: start, color: holiday.color })
    })
    const leaves = []
    this.state.absentiesList.forEach((leave) => {
        let start_at = (new Date(leave.start_at))
        let end_at = (new Date(leave.end_at))
        leaves.push({ id: leave.id, name: leave.username, startDate: start_at, endDate: end_at, color: leave.color })
    })
    const list = [...holidays, ...leaves]
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { validated, loading } = this.state;
    const me = this;
    return (
        <div>
            <Calendar
                enableRangeSelection={true}
                enableContextMenu={true}
                onDayEnter={e => this.handleDayEnter(e)}
                onRangeSelected={e => {
                    let fields = this.state.fields;
                    fields['for_date'] = e.startDate;
                    this.setState({ fields })
                    me.setState({ currentEvent: { startDate: e.startDate } })
                }}
                dataSource={list}

            />
            <Dialog open={this.state.currentEvent} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title" onClose={this.closeForm}>

                <div>

                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Holiday</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        {this.state.currentEvent && (
                            <form noValidate validated={validated.toString()} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth error={this.state.errors.occasion ? true : false}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="occasion">Occasion name</InputLabel>
                                    <Input id="occasion" name="occasion" autoComplete="occasion" autoFocus value={this.state.currentEvent.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                    {this.state.errors.occasion && <FormHelperText>{this.state.errors.occasion}</FormHelperText>}
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth >
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="for_date">From</InputLabel>
                                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                        <Grid container justify="space-around">
                                            <KeyboardDatePicker
                                                autoOk
                                                variant="dialog"
                                                format="yyyy/MM/dd"
                                                margin="normal"
                                                id='for_date'
                                                name='for_date'
                                                value={this.state.currentEvent.startDate}
                                                onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

                                </FormControl>
                                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth error={this.state.errors.is_restricted ? true : false}>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        control={<Checkbox name="checkbox" value={this.state.fields.is_restricted} color="primary" onChange={this.handleInputChange} checked={this.state.fields.is_restricted} />}
                                        label="Restricted holiday ?"
                                    />
                                </FormControl>


                                <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary"   >
                                    Save
                                </Button>
                            </form>
                        )}
                    </DialogContent>
                </div>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

i am able to create the event but i want that when i click on created event date, it should open with existing holiday and i should be able to update it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

resolved this issue by doing this code

```
toggleEditModal = event => {
    if (event.type == 'holiday') {
        if (!this.state.isAddModalOpen) {
            let fields = this.state.fields;
            fields['is_restricted'] = event.resource;
            fields["occasion"] = event.title;
            fields['for_date'] = event.start;
            fields['id'] = event.id;
            this.setState({
                fields,
                currentEvent: event,
                isEditModalOpen: !this.state.isEditModalOpen,
            });
        }
    }
};
```